# IE 9 (Browser mode:ie9, document mode:standards) supports CSS3 box-shadow?

Tags: css

Is IE really support CSS3 `box-shadow`? thanks.

```
a {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #6CAB00 0px, #486E00 90%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #315100;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #BBED62 inset;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE supports box-shadow CSS3 on the new versions. What version of IE you use?

Comment: +1, I am using IE10 (Browser mode :IE9 ; Document mode: standards). thanks.